# Mocking data into AG-Grid and testing with react testing library / Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, ag-grid, react-testing-library

I am trying to use my mock data for AG Grid to test with and I cannot find a solution to it. I have tried many things and have been working on it for days. I am trying to use the mock data to populate in the grid to test with. Using react testing library and Jest. Ive tried mocking the data with jest.fn(), jest.mock, etc. but I cant get anything to work. Below is a link to the code. Theres more Mock data, just put one date to show what file im using. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to render the mock data in mockData.js into the AG Grid to test for. If anyone has any pointers or help I would appreciate it. Thank you.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1CPNNNuPyaj7hgSe

```
const GridExample = () => {
  const containerStyle = { width: '100%', height: '100%' };

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    { date: '12/12/2022  3:00PM' },
    { date: '10/31/2022  7:00PM' },
    { date: '10/30/2022  7:00AM' },
    { date: '10/1/2022  8:00AM' },
    { date: '8/31/2022  4:59PM' },
  ]);
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'date' },
  ]);


  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div style={containerStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
        ></AgGridReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<GridExample></GridExample>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

// Theres more tests, testing the row data but no mocked data is being displayed.
// Ive tried jest.fn(), jest.mock, etc

```
  const waitForGridToBeInTheDOM = () => waitFor(() => {
    expect(document.querySelector('.ag-root-wrapper')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  const waitForDataToHaveLoaded = () => waitFor(() => {
    expect(document.querySelector('.ag-overlay-no-rows-center')).toBeNull();
  });

describe('date Tests', function () {
   beforeEach(async function () {
    render(<GridExample />);

    await waitForGridToBeInTheDOM();
    await waitForDataToHaveLoaded();
  });

  test('should render date grid', function () {
  });
  test('should expect date grid to render with Date column', async function () {
    expect(screen.getByText('Date')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
};
```

// Mock file mockDate.js

```
const mockDataTest = {
  date: "01/01/2022 12:00PM",
  date: "08/07/2022 9:00PM",
  date: "10/01/2022 10:00PM",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
A better working approach is wrapping the expectation with 'waitFor', this way it will try to assert it multiple times till it eventually succeeds.

```
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText('Date')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```